# Win Error 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, sockets

I have been experimenting with the socket library for python. I made a simple program for the server and client where the client can message the server.

### Here is my code for the server:

```
import socket

print("Host")

socket_main = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_main.bind(('127.0.0.1', 9999))

socket_main.listen(1)
conn, addr = socket_main.accept()

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1204).decode()
    print(data)

conn.close()
```

### Here is my code for the client

```
import socket

print("Client")

socket_main = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_main.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9999))

while True:
    message = input(": ")
    socket_main.send(message.encode())

socket_main.close()
```

When I run these programs in two different terminals on one computer it works just fine, but when I try to run the server and client on different computers I get an error on the clients end saying, "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I have tried changing the port multiple times but it didn't help. I have looked through a lot of other forums and I haven't been able to fix this problem for a while now so I decided to ask here.

Comment: @WardenUnleashed that won't work across the network, either

Comment: I misread. Didnt see they were trying to connect cross-network!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I try to run the server and client on different computers I get an error on the clients end

That is because you are using`127.0.0.1` on both sides.  That is the localhost loopback IP address. It works when the client and server are on the same machine, but it is not routable on the LAN network.

You need to:

- change the server to listen on either `0.0.0.0` (to listen on all installed network interfaces), or its actual LAN IP address (just the network interface attached to the LAN).
- change the client to connect to the server's hostname or IP address on the LAN.

> I have tried changing the port multiple times but it didn't help

The problem is nit with the port, but with the IP address.

Comment: Do you means doing this on the server: socket_main.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9999)), and this on the client: socket_main.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9999))

Comment: @sashasmol26 yes for the server, no for the client. `socket.gethostname()` returns the local machine's hostname, so calling that on the client machine would return the client's hostname, not the server's. But, you could have the server display the result of `gethostname()` and then you can enter that value into the client.

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks